# decreasing sequence of open subgroups, projective limit, p-adic integers

Tags: metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

> Let $U=\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ast}$ be the group of p-adic units. We put $U_n=1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. $U_n$ form a decreasing sequence of open subgroups of $U$, and $U=\displaystyle{\lim_{\leftarrow}}~ U/U_n$

That $U_n\supseteq U_m$ for $m>n$ is clear.
Choose $x\in U_m$, then $x\equiv 1\mod p^m$. Since $p^m>p^n$ we get $p^{m}=p^{n+k}=p^{n}p^{k}$. Hence $x\equiv 1\mod p^n$ and $x\in U_n$.

How can I see, that the $U_n$ are open in $U$?
What is the topology?
The only metric (in the p-adic context) I know is for $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $d(x,y)=e^{-v_p(x-y)}$. Is it the same metric?

How can we see, that $U=\displaystyle{\lim_{\leftarrow}}~ U/U_n$.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Why can we reduce to $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when we go to $\displaystyle{\lim_{\leftarrow}} (\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I'd say $\varprojlim U/U_n= \varprojlim (\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p)^\times= \varprojlim (\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times = \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. For openness  $\mathbb{Z}_p, p^n \mathbb{Z}_p,1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_p,|.|_p$ (for any point $a$ it contains a neighborhood $\{|a-b| < |p_n|_p\}$) and $U_n$ is also a topological open subgroup of $U=\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ (topology of $|.|_p$ making the multiplication continuous) which is related to the fact $U/U_n$ is finite/compact.

Comment: Do you refer with $|\cdot|_p$ to the metric I have given above? $U/U_n$ is finite, does that already imply that it is compact?

Comment: Sure $|a p^n|_p = e^{-n}$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}, p \nmid a$ (where $e$ is any fixed real number $> 1$, usually we take $e = p$). $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ for $|.|_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times = \{ a \in \mathbb{Z}_p, |a|_p = 1\}$. Equivalently $\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim (\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Comment: I thought $e$ is Euler's number. Then with $|\cdot|_p=d(x,y)=e^{-v_p(x-y)}$ we get $|ap^n|_p=e^{-v_p(ap^n)}=e^{-n}$ where $p\nmid a$. Is that correct? How can we proof for example, that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with this metric.

Comment: See my comment above I showed why (of course you need know how to define $p^n \mathbb{Z}$ in term of $|.|_p$). The value of $e > 1$ doesn't change the topology and the fact $|.|_p$ is a non-Archimedian absolute value.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you addressed this in your comment above, but I would like to give a "complete" proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a\in\Bbb Z_p$ and $r>0$ let $D(a,r)=\{x\in\Bbb Z_p:|x-a|_p<r\}$ be the open disc of center $a$ and radious $r$ in $\Bbb Z_p$.
For each $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $U_n=1+p^n\Bbb Z_p=D(1,r)$ for $|p^n|_p<r\leq|p^{n-1}|_p$, thus it's an open disc.
The projections $U\to U/U_n$ induces a group homomorphism
$$\varphi:U\to\lim_\leftarrow U/U_n$$
by universal property of projective limit.
The kernel of this homomorphism is $\bigcap_n U_n=\{1\}$, hence it's injective.

For surjectivity, first note that $U=\Bbb Z_p\setminus p\Bbb Z_p$, that's a $p$-adic integer is invertible if and only if it's not divisible by $p$, thus $U$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb Z_p$, because $p\Bbb Z_p$ is an open disc.
As closed subset of the complete space $\Bbb Z_p$, $U$ is also complete.
Let $v_n\in\lim U/U_n,n\in\Bbb N$ be a sequence.
Write $v_n=u_nU_n$ with $u_n\in U$.
Then for $m\geq n$ we have
$$|u_m-u_n|_p=\left|\frac{u_m}{u_n}-1\right|_p\leq e^{-n}$$
because $u_m/u_n\in U_n$ being $u_m\equiv u_n\pmod{U_n}$.
Thus $u_n$ is a Cauchy sequence which converges to some $u\in U$ and $\varphi(u)=v$.

Alternatively, if you defined $\Bbb Z_p$ as $\lim\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, then you get the isomorphism $U\cong\lim(\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z)^\times$ because the forgetful functor (which takes a ring into the group of invertible elements) preserve limits.
But $U_n$ is the kernel of surjective group homomorphism $U\to(\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z)^\times$ induced by $\Bbb Z_p\to\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, hence $U/U_n\cong\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, hence again $U\cong\lim U/U_n$.

Comment: I do not know much about projective limits. Could you explain what the universal property of projective limits is?

Comment: Whenever you have a family of group homomorphism $\varphi_n:U\to U/U_n$ such that $\varphi_m(x)$ and $\varphi_n(x)$ determine the same coset modulo $U_m$ for $m\geq n$ and $x\in U$, then there exists a unique $\varphi$ such that $\varphi_n(x)=\varphi(x)U_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I might ask some more questions to your answer, but I have to go through it first. :)